# Sinon fake callOnce not detecting call for second async call

Tags: javascript, async-await, sinon

Following is the code where my second fake is not detecting that call has been made.

I have a class with creator function. The creator function returns a class which has few async functions.

```
const parentfn = {
  fn1: async x => { return x + 1 },
  fn2: async y => { return y + 2 },
  fn3: (text) => {
      console.error('Warning::', text)
      return
    }
}

const testClass = {
  createParent: () => parentfn
}

const testMainFuntion = async (tc) => {
  const parent = tc.createParent()
  const var1 = await parent.fn1(1)
  const var2 = await parent.fn2(1)
  parent.fn3(var1 + var2)
}
```

That class is then passed to actual method which is what I am trying to test. It seemed like the test should be passing.

```
// Unit Test
it('should return updated value to the user', () => {
  // testMainFuntion(testClass);
  const fakeFn1 = sinon.fake.resolves(0)
  const fakeFn2 = sinon.fake.resolves(0)
  const fakeFn3 = sinon.fake();
  const fakeParent = {
    fn1: fakeFn1,
    fn2: fakeFn2,
    fn3: fakeFn3
  }
  const fakeCreate = {
    createParent: () => fakeParent
  }
  testMainFuntion(fakeCreate)
  //Passes
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(fakeFn1)
  //Fails
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(fakeFn2)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need one small change.

Wait for `testMainFuntion` to complete before asserting:

```
it('should return updated value to the user', async () => {  // <= use async test function
  // testMainFuntion(testClass);
  const fakeFn1 = sinon.fake.resolves(0)
  const fakeFn2 = sinon.fake.resolves(0)
  const fakeFn3 = sinon.fake();
  const fakeParent = {
    fn1: fakeFn1,
    fn2: fakeFn2,
    fn3: fakeFn3
  }
  const fakeCreate = {
    createParent: () => fakeParent
  }
  await testMainFuntion(fakeCreate)  // wait for testMainFuntion to complete
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(fakeFn1)  // SUCCESS
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(fakeFn2)  // SUCCESS
})
```

Comment: Thank you. This indeed passed the above test condition. I, however, fixed it later using `done` and calling `done()` after each assertion. 


This approach passed the test for all the `calledOnce` but threw a fit for `calledWith.match`